# Partition issues after deleting Core Storage Logical Volume Group. Everything prompts an unmount error

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I followed the instructions in [Restore Macintosh HD to its original partition configuration](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139157/restore-macintosh-hd-to-its-original-partition-configuration) to delete the Core Storage Logical Volume Group via terminal while pressing Cmd+R during startup.
These are the functions I used in terminal:

```
diskutil cs list
diskutil cs delete <Logical Volume Group UUID>
```

Now I cannot resize the partition via Disk Utility. The post mentioned that a red error message would appear when selecting the drive, but that didn't happen.  I'm stuck!

When I try entering "diskutil cs list" in Terminal it returns:

```
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found.
```

These are screenshots from the errors in Disk Utility:

[image: Disk Utility]

After resizing the top partition by dragging down and clicking "Apply", an error message prompts: "Couldn't unmount disk". Also happens after I repair the disk.

[image: Couldn't unmount disk.]

When restarting the computer, a grey screen with error icon appears.

[image: Error icon on boot]

Comment: Rule 1 - don't try to repartition your boot drive, whilst you're booted from it.

Comment: Tetsujin: Instead of rephrasing the obvious lesson learned, do you have a solution?

Comment: Try picking through http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154964/resizing-or-expanding-a-corestorage-volume/154969#154969 or go for Internet Recovery

Comment: @chrisshon You can't expect two red signed hdds after deleting the CoreStorage volume if you don't have an original or DIY-Fusion drive. Is your volume empty or does it contain some data or a system?

Comment: @klanomath this is the original drive. What do you mean by "volume"? Before this occurred, I used Migration assistant to restore from a Time machine backup.  Im fine with losing all the data as I can always do another migration.

Comment: @Tetsujin I was going through the link you posted, but when trying to create a disk image of 'Recovery HD' I get an error prompt: "The disk "Recovery HD" could not be unmounted. Please check that all applications and files are closed on this disk."

Also - When I enter "diskutil cs list" in terminal it returns "No CoreStorage" logical volume groups found."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend:

1. Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by  pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.
   The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
   On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot into the recovery netboot image which is loaded from an apple server.
2. In the opening window choose 'Disk Utility' and erase/format/partition the internal drive. Choose '1 Partition' 'Mac OS Extended (Journaled)' and GUID partition table (available with the 'Option' button). Quit 'Disk Utility'.
3. Plug in your Time Machine backup drive.
4. Start 'Restore From Time Machine Backup' and recover your old system

Instead of recovering your old system after step 2 you may install a new system by clicking on 'Reinstall OS X' and continue later with the steps 3. & 4. and recover your personal data only:

[image: reinstall OS X]

Comment: I don't have time machine

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Recovery Mode (hold down Command+R on startup) . Restore your computer or try to partion it through the Recovery HD.

Comment: When I try to Restore, it says that the Recovery HD is locked.  How would I partition through Recovery HD?

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps:

1. Hold down <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> on Apple keyboard or <kbd>Window</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> on a PC keyboard.
2. Format or fix the partition.

Once complete, you will be able to download the OS that came installed on your computer.

Comment: So...given that the OP is already using recovery mode in an attempt to fix the problem, how does this add to the available solutions?