# Restoring Fusion Drive after error on partition erase

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, partition, core-storage, fusion-drive

I think I'm lost and need some help with my Fusion Drive.
I have new iMac Retina 5k with 3TB Fusion Drive and preinstalled Yosemite.

Things I did so far:

1. I was working on my iMac and had successfully deployed Bootcamp partition with Windows 7 (120gb). Everything went well, but after some time, the Win7 partition filled up so I decided to find a way to make it larger. Moral of the story is 'don't change something that works'.
2. After some Googling I've found that nothing but removing and reinstalling Bootcamp worked in that matter.
3. I backed up my Win7 partition with Clonezilla and than removed it with BA.
4. Started BA anew, made new partition (399gb), new installation USB flash drive than restarted to install with same BA.
5. Windows 7 installation started, found new and empty BOOTCAMP partition but couldn't install Win7 on it, formatting it didn't help (later I found that it was caused by my external HDD plugged in).
6. Restarted to OSX. Then the bad things started to happen.
7. In DU I clicked Erase on BOOTCAMP partition, it gave me an error and BOOTCAMP partiton disappeared. It still showed on Disk view as unallocated space.
8. I thought that removing what left from Bootcamp partition and expanding current CS to full size would enable BA partition splitting again.
9. I went along these steps [Restore Macintosh HD to its original partition configuration](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139157/restore-macintosh-hd-to-its-orig) inal-partition-configuration
10. It didn't work. In a last frantic attempt, I deleted whole cs, but it didn't fix to a new Fusion Drive.

So now I'm stuck with scrambled fusion drive and don't know what to do.
I want to restore Fusion Drive to original, unsliced state and than put working Bootcamp partition there.

Here is screenshot from DU in debug mode (sorry it's in polish) are listings for various diskutil commands in terminal:

[image: Disk Utility screenshot]
[image: More Disk Utility details]

diskutil list

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS SSD                     121.0 GB   disk0s2
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         1.8 TB     disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *1.3 GB     disk2
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        1.3 GB     disk2s2
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Untitled               *1.8 TB     disk3
                                 Logical Volume on disk1s2
                                 8FDEBC56-0DCC-4A11-83A2-ACC38C44ABC0
                                 Unencrypted
/dev/disk4
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *5.2 MB     disk4
/dev/disk5
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk5
/dev/disk6
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk6
/dev/disk7
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk7
/dev/disk8
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk8
/dev/disk9
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk9
/dev/disk10
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *6.3 MB     disk10
/dev/disk11
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *2.1 MB     disk11
/dev/disk12
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *1.0 MB     disk12
/dev/disk13
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk13
/dev/disk14
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk14
/dev/disk15
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *1.0 MB     disk15
/dev/disk16
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *6.3 MB     disk16
```

diskutil cs list

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 4D59CB69-60DE-49BB-8450-B573CD66DA1B
    =========================================================
    Name:         Untitled
    Status:       Online
    Size:         1799162331136 B (1.8 TB)
    Free Space:   7237632 B (7.2 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume B5EF6237-F28B-4F00-8897-CDCBDAFF5F64
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     1799162331136 B (1.8 TB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family A43C4760-0885-4D62-AB53-5F6CABA63AB6
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         None
        Conversion Status:       NoConversion
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   No
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     No
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 8FDEBC56-0DCC-4A11-83A2-ACC38C44ABC0
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk3
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          1798802767872 B (1.8 TB)
            Conversion Progress:   -none-
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Untitled
            Volume Name:           Untitled
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

gpt -vv -r show /dev/disk0

```
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=121332826112; sectorsize=512; blocks=236978176
gpt show: /dev/disk0: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 236978175
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  236306352      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  236715992     262151         
  236978143         32         Sec GPT table
  236978175          1         Sec GPT header
```

gpt -vv -r show /dev/disk1

```
gpt show: /dev/disk1: mediasize=3000592982016; sectorsize=512; blocks=5860533168
gpt show: /dev/disk1: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk1: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk1: Sec GPT at sector 5860533167
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  3513988928      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  3514398568     1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  3515668104  2344865031         
  5860533135          32         Sec GPT table
  5860533167           1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: @IconDaemon thank You, English is not my first language.

Answer (score 1):

The way to deal with this is by separating the fusion drive, reformatting each drive, and recreating them. I suspect what's happened is your Mac cannot recognize the NTFS formatted portion of the disk.

Reboot while holding Alt + Cmd + R for Internet Recovery Mode. Go to Utilities > Terminal, and in terminal type: diskutil cs list, then find the UUID under "Logical Volume Group" with the missing space, copy it, and paste it after: diskutil cs delete. Go back to Disk Utility. At the prompt, click "OK" to repair your Fusion Drive. Exit Disk Utility, reboot (to the recovery partition if it doesn't automatically, to Internet Recovery Mode, or using a recovery USB drive) and reinstall OS X. When that finishes: If you plan on restoring from a Time Machine backup, you may have to create a new User and recover your old account logged in as the new one. If this does not work, you may have to manually reformat each drive, and proceed from step one.